# How to get information from the elements in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

How to get information from this elements?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
chrome_options.add_extension('cs2float.crx') #https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/csfloat-market-checker/jjicbefpemnphinccgikpdaagjebbnhg
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AWP%20%7C%20Safari%20Mesh%20%28Field-Tested%29?filter=')
s = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"market_listing_row")
print(s)
```

result:

```
\[\<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d4c3d8ed66ec73b70201767ecffa1b24", element="2224FFC6637A62C90C8E453E269470D2_element_20")\>, \<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d4c3d8ed66ec73b70201767ecffa1b24", element="2224FFC6637A62C90C8E453E269470D2_element_21")\>, \<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d4c3d8ed66ec73b70201767ecffa1b24", element="2224FFC6637A62C90C8E453E269470D2_element_22")\>, \<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d4c3d8ed66ec73b70201767ecffa1b24", element="2224FFC6637A62C90C8E453E269470D2_element_23")\>, \<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d4c3d8ed66ec73b70201767ecffa1b24", element="2224FFC6637A62C90C8E453E269470D2_element_24")\>, \<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d4c3d8ed66ec73b70201767ecffa1b24", element="2224FFC6637A62C90C8E453E269470D2_element_25")\>, \<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d4c3d8ed66ec73b70201767ecffa1b24", element="2224FFC6637A62C90C8E453E269470D2_element_26")\>, \<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d4c3d8ed66ec73b70201767ecffa1b24", element="2224FFC6637A62C90C8E453E269470D2_element_27")\>, \<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d4c3d8ed66ec73b70201767ecffa1b24", element="2224FFC6637A62C90C8E453E269470D2_element_28")\>, \<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d4c3d8ed66ec73b70201767ecffa1b24", element="2224FFC6637A62C90C8E453E269470D2_element_29")\>, \<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d4c3d8ed66ec73b70201767ecffa1b24", element="2224FFC6637A62C90C8E453E269470D2_element_30")\>\]
```

I need to get information about the float and the price of the skin.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text of your elements simply call `.text` while iterating:

```
s = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".market_listing_row .market_table_value")
for e in s:
    print(e.text)
```

Be aware that I changed you selector to be more specific. This will lead to:

```
2,21₴
27,71₸
5,55 pуб.
¥ 0.42
¥ 0.42
5,60 pуб.
5,60 pуб.
5,60 pуб.
5,60 pуб.
5,60 pуб.
```

To get cleaner results may use additionally `regex` to extract the specific parts from the text:

```
import re
for e in s:
    price =float(re.search("\d+[\.|,]\d+", e.text).group(0).replace(',','.'))
    currency = re.search("[^\d|\,|\.]+", e.text).group(0).strip()
    print(price,currency)
```

This will give you:

```
2.21 ₴
2.21 ₴
2.21 ₴
2.21 ₴
2.21 ₴
2.21 ₴
5.54 pуб
27.71 ₸
5.55 pуб
0.29 R$
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through the list of element `s`.

```
s = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"market_listing_row")
for element in s:
    print(element.get_attribute("class"))
    print(element.text)
```

You can learn what and how to handle and play with web elements in selenium [here link](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html)

Answer (score 0):

To get element content you need to get it's `.text` property in case if it is visible or attribute `innerText` if it exists but is not visible.

So you need to loop through weapon containers and get texts from `.market_listing_price_with_fee`.

However, getting float value from extension is a bit complicated as far as it generates it's own `shadow-root` that contains only `div` element and content in it is loaded async.

So, you need to get `shadow-host` from `csfloat-item-row-wrapper`, get it's `shadowRoot` property via JS executor and then get `innerText` from the only `div`.

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
chrome_options.add_extension('3.2.0_0.crx') #https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/csfloat-market-checker/jjicbefpemnphinccgikpdaagjebbnhg
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AWP%20%7C%20Safari%20Mesh%20%28Field-Tested%29?filter=')
containers = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class*=market_listing_row][id*=listing]')))
time.sleep(2) # dirty wait for script to be loaded
for container in containers:
    print("Price: ")
    print(container.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.market_listing_price_with_fee').get_attribute('innerText'))
    extension_container = WebDriverWait(container, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'csfloat-item-row-wrapper')))
    shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', extension_container)

    content = shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div')

    content_text = content.get_attribute('innerText')
    result = content_text.replace('\n', ' ').split(' ')
    print(result[0])
    print(result[1])
```